# Interval of existence for second order equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find an interval of existence centered about $x=0$ for which the given initial value problem has a unique solution.
$$y''+y\tan x=e^x \qquad, \quad y(0)=y'(0)=0$$

Why is the interval of the differential equation the domain of $\tan x$ containing $x=0$,$(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. I thought the determination of the interval  was based on the coefficient of the highest order derivative?

If the differential equation had been a hypothetical
$$(x-2)y''+y\tan x=e^x \qquad, \quad y(0)=y'(0)=0$$

would the interval be $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\cap(-\infty,2)$?

i.e. if the differential equation is of the form:

$a_n(x)y^n+\ldots+a_1(x)y'+a_0(x)y=g(x)$

Is the interval dependent upon the where the function $a_n(x)  is \neq 0 $ and where all the other functions  ${a}_{n-1}(x),...,a_0(x),g(x)$ are not defined?

Is it the intersection of all these intervals containing the particular centered x value?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is true if all the coefficients $a_k$ are continuous. You can transform the given ODE to this state by multiplying it with $\cos x$,
$$
\cos(x)y''(x)+\sin(x)y(x)=\cos(x)e^x
$$
Then indeed the roots of $a_2(x)=\cos(x)$ restrict the domain of the solution.

You could also take the alternative rule that the domain of the solution of a linear ODE with leading coefficient $1$ is the maximal interval containing the initial point where all the coefficients are continuous. And the tangent has discontinuities at $\pm\frac\pi2$.